# Ipython - persistent variables between sessions

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I would like to be able to use python in a way that I can save a session with the data, load it up and carry on with the variables that were in memory. Some of the variables can be fairly large (~1GB), so I would rather not have to read them from the CSV file each time I want to use them.

If I was able to do this for different projects, that would be ideal, I'm not sure how to do so though.